# Forth Roots of $17$ in the P-adic Numbers

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Does $2y^2=x^4-17$ have a root in every P-adic number field?

My answer is yes, using Hensels lemma.

Let $f(x)=x^4-17$ (all coefficients have P-adic norm less than $1$ for each P-adic norm), let $a$=1, then for $p \neq 2$ we have

$|f(a)|_p=|16|_p=1 < 4=|4a^3|_p^2=|f'(a)|_p^2$

and so $f$ has a root by Hensels lemma.

For $p=2$ we have

$|f(a)|_2=16^{-1}<4^{-1}=|f'(a)|_2^2$

so again, by Hensels lemma, there is a root.

Is this correct? It feels too easy.

Comment: You seem to imply that $4=|4|_p$, which is never true. Also, note that $17$ can't have an $n^{\text{th}} $ root in $\mathbb{Q}_{17}$ (with $n>1 $) because this root would have a valuation of $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @JoelCohen Thanks, knew I was doing something wrong.